# CERN ROOT: generate streamer for an extern "C" struct in a namespace

Tags: c++, serialization, io, root-framework

Let us assume one has `struct MyStruct` declared in file "MyStruct.h".

```cpp
// file MyStruct.h
#ifndef MY_STRUCT_H
#define MY_STRUCT_H
/*****************************************************/
#if defined(__cplusplus)
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
   extern "C"
   {
#endif
typedef struct Inner {       
    char ch[2];
} Inner;       
#if defined(__cplusplus)
   } /* extern "C" */
} /* namespace */
#endif
/*****************************************************/
struct MyStruct { SomeNameSpace::Inner inner; };

//using namespace SomeNameSpace;
//struct MyStruct { Inner inner; };
/*****************************************************/
#endif
```

How can one write such a struct as a branch of a ROOT TTree? Note, I can not remove the

```cpp
#if defined(__cplusplus)
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
   extern "C"
   {
```

wrapping since it is defined in an external library header.

ROOT gives me the following error:

```
root [0] gROOT->LoadMacro("MyStruct.h+")
Info in <TUnixSystem::ACLiC>: creating shared library .../MyStruct_h.so
Error in <CloseStreamerInfoROOTFile>: Cannot find class Inner.
Error in <ACLiC>: Dictionary generation failed!
(int) -1
```

Everything works, if I remove the `namespace`, i.e. the following code works:

```cpp
// file MyStruct.h
#ifndef MY_STRUCT_H
#define MY_STRUCT_H
/*****************************************************/
#if defined(__cplusplus)
   extern "C"
   {
#endif
typedef struct Inner {       
    char ch[2];
} Inner;       
#if defined(__cplusplus)
   } /* extern "C" */
#endif
/*****************************************************/
struct MyStruct { Inner inner; };
/*****************************************************/
#endif
```

i.e. ROOT gives:

```
root [0] gROOT->LoadMacro("MyStruct.h+")
Info in <TUnixSystem::ACLiC>: creating shared library .../MyStruct_h.so
(int) 0
root [1] MyStruct x;
root [2] TFile f("temp.root", "recreate");
root [3] TTree t("t","");
root [4] t.Branch("x", &x); // no errors :-)
```

Maybe something can be done with a `MyStruct_Linkdef.h` file:

```cpp
// rootcling -f MyStructDict.cxx -c MyStruct.h MyStruct_Linkdef.h
// g++ -shared -o libMyStruct.so `root-config --ldflags` ${CXXFLAGS} -I${ROOTSYS}/include -std=c++17 -fPIC MyStructDict.cxx

//#ifdef __CINT__

#pragma link off all functions;
#pragma link off all globals;
#pragma link off all classes;

#pragma link C++ nestedclass;
#pragma link C++ nestedtypedef;
#pragma link C++ namespace SomeNameSpace;
//#pragma link C++ class MyStruct;
//#pragma link C++ class SomeNameSpace::MyStruct;
//#pragma link C++ defined_in "MyStruct.h";

//#endif
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for the problem:

```cpp
#ifndef MY_STRUCT_H
#define MY_STRUCT_H
/*****************************************************/
#if defined(__cplusplus)
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
   extern "C"
   {
#endif
typedef struct Inner {
    char ch[2];
} Inner;
#if defined(__cplusplus)
   } /* extern "C" */
} /* namespace */
#endif
/*****************************************************/
using Inner = SomeNameSpace::Inner;
struct MyStruct { Inner inner; };
/*****************************************************/
#endif
```